# Java: Custom Global exception handler always returns 200 status

Tags: java, rest, exception

I created a global exception handler for my program which is working and catches my exceptions but when I try to get the status code from the HttpServletResponse, I always get a 200 status. Is there any way I can get the right status from the exception class? Or if you have another work around I'd appreciate it. Can't find anything online and I don't want to hardcode an httpStatus for every exception that goes through my handler. I want to catch all exceptions with this one method. This is the method I created in a my GlobalExceptionHandler class (also fyi I used the @ControllerAdvice annotation for the class):

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<Object> error(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Exception e) throws Exception {

    log.error("Error in call to " + request.getRequestURI() + " Response: " + response.toString(), e);

    ExceptionResource exception = new ExceptionResource();
    exception.setLocation(request.getRequestURI());
    exception.setStatus(response.getStatus());
    exception.setStackTrace(e.getStackTrace());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(exception, HttpStatus.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:** I had to think of another implementation but I did find a way to get the status of custom exceptions created using @ResponseStatus annotations. You will want to use this to get the status:

```
 HttpStatus status = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(exception.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class).value();
```

where exception is the exception being passed to the handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring MVC, your exception needs to have something like this :

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="No such Order")
public class OrderNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    // ...
}
```

[source](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)